# JDBC connection for a background thread being closed accessing in Websphere

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, websphere

I have an application running in Websphere Portal Server inside of Websphere Application Server 6.0 (WAS). In this application for one particular functionality that takes a long time to complete, I am firing a new thread that performs this action. This new thread opens a new Session from Hibernate and starts performing DB transactions with it. Sometimes (haven't been able to see a pattern), the transactions inside the thread work fine and the process completes successfully.  Other times however I get the errors below:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [OBJECT NAME#218294]
...
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.
Method cleanup failed while trying to execute method cleanup on ManagedConnection WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@642aa0d8 from resource jdbc/MyJDBCDataSource. Caught exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: DSRA0080E: An exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original exception message: Cannot call 'cleanup' on a ManagedConnection while it is still in a transaction..
```

How can I stop this from happening? Why does it seem that WAS wants to kill my connections even though they're not done. Is there a way I can stop WAS from attempting to close this particular connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mentioned two possible causes in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648422/configure-hibernate-to-obtain-a-fresh-connection-from-a-connection-pool/2649690#2649690): 1. the  `hibernate.connection.release_mode` optional parameter or 2. a problem with [unmanaged threads](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html#spring-4). Now that I read this question, I really start to think that your problem may be related to the fact that you're spawning your own threads. Since they aren't managed by the container, connections used in these treads may appear as "leaked" (not closed properly) and I wouldn't be surprised if WAS tries to recover them at some point.

If you want to start a long running job, you should use a WorkManager. Don't spawn threads yourself.

Comment: I will look into WorkManager, do you know of any examples for this?

Comment: @ferrari You could start here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/asyncbns/concepts/casb_workmgr.html