# Configure Hibernate to obtain a fresh connection from a connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jdbc, websphere

How do I configure Hibernate so that each time I call sessionFactory.openSession() it connects with a new connection from the connection pool? The connection pool is managed by Websphere Application Server and is a JDBC Data Source.

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for this requirement?  To avoid stale connections in the pool?

Comment: I need to open 2 sessions in a single request in a web application. Right now, it appears that both sessions are using the same connection, because when the first session is closed (manually calling session.close()) sometimes, the other session will throw a "session closed" exception when trying to run more queries on it. The second session is open by a child thread which means that the child thread can keep living even after the (HTTP) request is complete.

Comment: Could you show a simplified code where the problem persist ? I think a session is 1:not thread safe, you should not pass a session object to another thread. 2:thread bound (depending on the tx mgnt stack you use). Do you open the two sessions in the same thread ? if yes try to open each of them in a different thread

Comment: I open 2 sessions in 2 different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I configure Hibernate so that each time I call sessionFactory.openSession() it connects with a new connection from the connection pool?

This is the default behavior, each session will get a **dedicated** connection from the connection pool.

> Right now, it appears that both sessions are using the same connection, because when the first session is closed (manually calling session.close()) sometimes, the other session will throw a "session closed" exception when trying to run more queries on it.

No they are not. But maybe the second connection gets released at the end of the transaction initiated for the request. Have a look at the `hibernate.connection.release_mode` [configuration parameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional), you might want to use `on_close`. But without more details on your transaction strategy, it's impossible to say anything.

> The second session is open by a child thread which means that the child thread can keep living even after the (HTTP) request is complete.

Take my previous advice with a grain of salt, you should just not spawn [unmanaged threads](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html#spring-4) and I don't know how the application server will behave. I explain in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647912/jdbc-connection-for-a-background-thread-being-closed-accessing-in-websphere/2649746#2649746) what would be the right way.